# why doesnt osx connect to some known wireless lans sometimes?

Tags: macos, wireless-router

though it knows the password, it doesnt connect and when I click on the particular wlan from the airport list it asks me for the password which I put and then I am connected to wlan.

This happens sometimes once a week or sometimes once a month. ALso I hav observed this behavior only with some wlans. for e.g. it doesnt happen at my university but happens at home.

might it be something with my home wlan router?

Comment: This is – in my experience – only a problem with either bad reception or bad routers. OS X shows a password prompt or a timeout then. Maybe you can tell us more about the networks that fail to connect?

Comment: Might be something to do with the wlan 'from the airport' expiring? Many of them are operated on DHCP leases which are set to expire.